# `sbt dist` silently exits without producing binary

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I used to be able to call `sbt dist` to package my play app into a binary, but (after making a lot of changes) when I try it, it just silently exists without giving any error or producing the binary. Here's the full output while running w/ `-verbose` and `-d` (debug):

```
$ sbt dist
[addSbt] arg = '-debug'
[residual] arg = '-sbt-create'
[residual] arg = 'dist'
[residual] arg = '-XX:MaxPermSize=50G'
[residual] arg = '-Xmx50G'
[residual] arg = 'dist'
[process_args] java_version = '14'
[sbt_options] declare -a sbt_options=()
[addMemory] arg = '1024'
[addJava] arg = '-Xms1024m'
[addJava] arg = '-Xmx1024m'
[addJava] arg = '-Xss4M'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m'
[copyRt] java9_rt = '/home/ali/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_14_0_1/rt.jar'
[addJava] arg = '-Dscala.ext.dirs=/home/ali/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_14_0_1'
# Executing command line:
java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Dscala.ext.dirs=/home/ali/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_14_0_1
-jar
/home/ali/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/1.3.13/bin/sbt-launch.jar
-debug
-XX:MaxPermSize=50G
-Xmx50G
dist

[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug] 
[debug] Other repositories:
[debug] Default repositories:
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug] 
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
$
```

And then it just exists and I'm back to the shell, and the binary isn't produced. In contrast, I used to see messages like `inflating xxx.yyy.zzz` etc.

The same thing happens when I run `sbt clean compile`:

```
[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug] 
[debug] Other repositories:
[debug] Default repositories:
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug] 
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
[debug] Checking for meta build source updates
```

And then it exits again, no error.

How can I get sbt to show some sort of error indicating why its not making the binary?

Using:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.2"
sbt.version=1.3.12
```

and Play 2.8.2

Comment: Removing these two lines from my `.sbtopts` file fixed the issue: `-XX:MaxPermSize=50G` and `-Xmx50G`. If anyone knows why these lines were causing this issue, please post and i'll accept your answer. Would love to know why they were the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing these two lines from my .sbtopts file fixed the issue: -XX:MaxPermSize=50G and -Xmx50G